# Excel Diverse List Comparison/Sorting?

Tags: excel, sorting, comparison

An alphanumeric list from two different sources ​with similar information ​
populating columns A and B.

How do I have excel match cells in column A and column B?

from:

```
123 |  DBA    
DBA |  ABC    
ABC |  123​    
A39 |  0PL​
```

​​to:

```
ABC |  ABC    
DBA |  DBA    
123 |  123    
​A39 |  0PL​
```

​

what is this process actually called?
and where might I find a process in how to accomplish this?
The specific program is Excel 2003, however, I expect the process is similar regardless of program version/type.
Thank you kindly for your assistance.

Comment: Seperate the two columns then use countif() in an adjacent to both columns to find if it is in the other column or not.  Then sort first on the count column then on the data column, do both individually then put them back together.

Comment: Thank you for your time in replying; And I am sorry for wasting your time, as I see now the expanse of my ignorance, and have no clue how to apply or use the term "countif() " stated.